# Numpy, Atlas and Lapack

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.3, lapack, atlas

I am using numpy for some array operations and it is currently extremely slow. The same operations in matlab (calculating the covariance matrix) only take a second. I have installed atlas and lapack but I am not sure if my numpy is actually using them. Does anyone know how to check that? 
I am using a mac

Comment: can you give more information (size of the array, functions used, etc)?

Comment: 22277 X 520 is the size of the array and I am using np.loadtxt() and no.cov(). They both take ages

Comment: What is the output of `numpy.show_config()`?

Comment: I get that:

blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
lapack_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']

Comment: after `covX = np.cov( X, rowvar=1 )` check that `covX.shape` is 520^2 and not 22277^2

Comment: Edit this information into your question, please

Comment: Using ATLAS won't speed up `np.loadtxt` in any case.

Answer (score 1):

To get numpy to use ATLAS you will either have to

- build it from source, setting up the site.cfg file so it can find your ATLAS libraries. This has just taken me most of the day to get to work on Gentoo (see [this bug report](http://bugs.funtoo.org/browse/FL-1224)), I'm not sure my experiences translate all that well to the Mac unfortunately.
- find a precompiled package that uses ATLAS. [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) or [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) might be good places to look, although they might only include optimised libraries in the paid-for versions - I'm not sure about this.